# Unable to Upload file in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

Hi all I am trying to upload file in php. But it is not uploading the file

Here is the code

```
$excel = new PhpExcelReader;
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $target_dir="../upload/";
    $target_path=$target_dir.basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);     

    //move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'],$target_path);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'],$target_path))
    {
        echo basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }
        print_r($_FILES);
    /* $handle = realpath($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $excel = new PhpExcelReader;
    $excel->read($handle);
    echo $handle; */

}
```

This code always throw me in else condition.In my html form I also added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and also check $_FILES array in my $_FILES array I am getting this

> Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => Copy of Book1.xlsx [type]
>   => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet [tmp_name] => H:\PHP\xampp\tmp\phpF54F.tmp [error] => 0 [size] =>
>   13459 ) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your if condition change it to `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],$target_path)`

Comment: thanks dude its works but why its not work with filename?

Comment: while uploading file on server it first store in temp location and `move_uploaded_file` function get file from temp location and upload in given destination location.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],$target_path))
{
    echo basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```