# Inpu type file not uploading file on submit, return empty array

Tags: php, file-upload

I am uploading the file on form submit it dose not show any detail when I check with `var_dump($FILES)` in php. It simply return an empty array.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    var_dump($_FILES);

//$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

 }
```

the result `array(0) { }`

Comment: what error/output do you get ?

Comment: not getting any error  just getting empty array  array(0) { }

Comment: Where are you checking the post data? is that in upload.php?

Comment: do you get the same result  with any size of files or just the big ones?, test with small size file.

Comment: yes @PramodPatil

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Upload file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729538/unable-to-upload-file-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Below performing file action, please set up below value in php.ini

```
file_uploads = On

post_max_size = 1000M

upload_max_filesize = 1000M
```